# Enable select even if options list is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-chosen

I am using [angular-chosen](https://leocaseiro.github.io/angular-chosen/#angular-chosen-localytics), by default if the source list is empty the element is disabled. Is there a way to enable the element even if the source list is empty?

Comment: What's the point to have it active but without items?

Comment: please post relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the [source code](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/blob/master/src/chosen.coffee) I can conclude that it's not possible (at least, without hacks).

You see, they are calling `disableIfEmpty` function and there's no way to control it.

They are watching `disabled` attribute changes, and when it changes - they update component. This was done to be compatible with `ng-disabled` directive. But it still won't help you if you want to enable empty select.

Also, if you manually run `$('[ng-model="myPets"]').removeAttr("disabled")` it won't really help you since they are not showing native select, but rather their own `div`: `<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-disabled"...`

So, if you really just want to make it look enabled - you can either apply this CSS:

```css
.chosen-disabled, .chosen-disabled * {
  opacity: unset !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

or this JS:

```js
$('.chosen-disabled').removeClass('chosen-disabled')
```

The proper solution would be to submit an issue or PR to their repo: https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen

Comment: Thank you for the Suggestion.

Comment: @MinalKumarThilakanath Please, don't forget to upvote the answer if you found it helpful. Thanks!